# Component for filtering a list

Tags: java, swing, list

What is the Java Swing component that would be suitable for creating a filterable list like seen below?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of filtering is most easily done using a single column `JTable`.  A table has inbuilt functionality to add a [`RowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) which:

> ..provides the basis for sorting **and filtering.**

See also [How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Here is an example for filtering the font family names:

[image]

On the left is a more 'list looking' component, while the right hand side shows a component that is clearly a table.

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class FontFilter {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    JTextField filterText;
    TableRowSorter sorter;

    FontFilter(boolean listLike) {
        initUI(listLike);
    }

    public void initUI(boolean listLike) {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        GraphicsEnvironment ge
                = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        String[][] tableData = new String[fonts.length][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
            tableData[i][0] = fonts[i];
        }
        String[] header = {"Fonts"};
        JTable table = new JTable(tableData, header);
        if (listLike) {
            Dimension d = table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(d.width/2,d.height));
            table.setShowGrid(false);
            table.setTableHeader(null);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        }
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        sorter = new TableRowSorter(table.getModel());
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        filterText = new JTextField(10);
        ui.add(filterText, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        Document doc = filterText.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        doc.addDocumentListener(listener);
    }
    
    private void newFilter() {
        RowFilter rf = null;
        //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
        try {
            rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0);
        } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                FontFilter o1 = new FontFilter(true);
                FontFilter o2 = new FontFilter(false);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Font Filter");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.add(o1.getUI(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                f.add(o2.getUI(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: RowSorter can be faster than to take the arrays of Object from whatever, sort by criteria, return back sorted array to model, more faster then sort in model at runtime, as aside important note, model for JComboBox/JList (where numbers of Items is more than 999, remove/At/All, replace, insert a few times here about this issue), has an performance issue in the case that you want to manipulate with whole data/Object from one code line, method

Comment: now I'm not able to remember the correct way for (performence issue) that, if to start with filtering, then to aply sorting or to filtering sorted view directly, don't know

Answer (score 1):

If you want or have to use only standard Swing components then the method described by @AndrewThompson is the way to go.

But if you are able to use third-party libraries then a good alternative is `JXList` component included in [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) project. This component is a `JList` extension and provides the ability to sort and filter its content plus other interesting features (check [SwingLabs Demos](https://swinglabs-demos.java.net/)).

The following snippet is the basis to make it work:

```
JXList list = new JXList(listModel);
list.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

This is enough to create and install a `RowSorter<ListModel, Integer>` instance as the list's row sorter which can be retrieved by calling `getRowSorter()` method. The actual object returned by this method is a `ListSortController` which inherits from `DefaultRowSorter` and also implements the non-standard `SortController` interface.

It is important to keep this class hierarchy in mind because it's possible to supply a `RowFilter` in different ways. All the following alternatives assume the row sorter is auto-created.

**Note:** IMO the first method is the preferred one because we can delegate the dirty work of down-casting the row sorter to supply a row filter to the component.

#### 1. Set the row filter directly on the list

```
list.setRowFilter(rowFilter);
```

This is a convenience method to set the row filter. However it is required by contract that the actual list's row sorter be a `SortController` compliant instance. Otherwise the `setRowFilter(...)` call has no effect.

#### 2. Cast the row sorter as `SortController`

```
SortController<ListModel> sortController 
        = (SortController<ListModel>)list.getRowSorter();
sortController.setRowFilter(rowFilter);
```

The `SortController` interface provides a method to set the row filter which is used to by-pass the row filter in the method # 1.

#### 3. Cast the row sorter as `DefaultRowSorter`

```
DefaultRowSorter<ListModel, Integer> sorter 
        = (DefaultRowSorter<ListModel, Integer>)list.getRowSorter();
sorter.setRowFilter(rowFilter);
```

This method is the same than when we are working with `JTable`.

#### Example

Here is a simple demo about filtering with `JXList`. Once again please check [SingLabs Demos](https://swinglabs-demos.java.net/) for better examples.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXList;    

public class FilterListDemo {

    private JXList list;

    private void createAndShowGui() {

        final JTextField filterText = new JTextField(30);
        filterText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                FilterListDemo.this.createFilter(filterText.getText(), false);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                FilterListDemo.this.createFilter(filterText.getText(), false);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                FilterListDemo.this.createFilter(filterText.getText(), false);
            }
        });

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

        list = new JXList(fonts);
        list.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8,8));
        content.add(filterText, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        content.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8,8,8,8));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Filter List Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createFilter(String text, final boolean caseSensitive) {

        final String filterText = caseSensitive ? text : text.toUpperCase();

        list.setRowFilter(new RowFilter<ListModel, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends ListModel
                    , ? extends Integer> entry) {

                String entryValue = caseSensitive 
                        ? entry.getStringValue(0) 
                        : entry.getStringValue(0).toUpperCase();

                return filterText == null 
                        || filterText.trim().isEmpty() 
                        || entryValue.contains(filterText.trim());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FilterListDemo().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```