# Java jTable changeSelection and then Highlight the new Selected Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jTable that contains many tickets and I want to give the user the option to find the ticket he is looking for and highlight that the same way that happens when you click on a ticket.

So as it appears in the following picture. Any ideas of how to highlight the ticket that the user selected? Not change the background color, but to make it look the same as if you have pressed on it.

[image: process picture]

```
 for (int tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < ticketTable.getRowCount(); tableIndex++) {

            if (ticketTableModel.getValueAt(tableIndex, 0).toString().equals(jTextField1.getText()) || ticketTableModel.getValueAt(tableIndex, 1).toString().equals(jTextField1.getText())) {
                ticketIndex = tableIndex;
                 ticketTable.requestFocus();

                ticketTable.changeSelection(drawIndex, 0, error, error);

                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: 1) *"I want the user to.."* I want you to ask a question (as opposed to simply outlining the requirement). What is the question? 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: See also [How to Use Tables: Sorting and **Filtering**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for what (I think) is a better overall approach to this. Here is a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28621618/418556) of what I mean.

Comment: Sorry for my complicated way to ask for the solution. You are right. The filtering is very useful. But I think is not the solutions I am looking for.

Comment: The changeSelection() method should be the method to use. Although I question why you are using "drawIndex" since the loop uses "tableIndex"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking to select a row at a certain index? You would do that by setting the selection interval through [`ListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29). You can get the selection model by calling [`JTable.getSelectionModel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel%28%29).

Applied to your example and with a few corrections:

```
String txt = jTextField1.getText();
for(int tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < ticketTable.getRowCount(); tableIndex++) {
    int rowModelId = ticketTable.convertRowIndexToModel(tableIndex);
    if(ticketTableModel.getValueAt(rowModelId,0).equals(txt) || ticketTableModel.getValueAt(rowModelId,1).equals(txt) {
        ticketTable.scrollRectToVisible(ticketTable.getCellRect(tableIndex,0));
        ticketTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(tableIndex,tableIndex);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ticketTable.scrollRectToVisible(tbl.getCellRect(tableIndex,0)); in this line. what tbl is?ticketTable?

Comment: I change your code to this and it does exactly what I want.. Thank you.  ticketTable.scrollRectToVisible(ticketTable.getCellRect(tableIndex,0,true));

Comment: @manoskammas The scrollRectToVisible method is there in case the row you want to select is not visible in the view.