# How update a jlist swing java

Tags: java, swing, jlist

[image]I had a problem. I am code a simple dictionary by using java swing
I want first to show all word and then whẹn i type a word or first of a word , it wI'll display this sublist . I try much but not successful, may someone help me

Comment: Please provide a **short** code example that illustrates what you are trying to do. For tips on creating a good example, read [mcve].

Comment: Don't post an image of your code. Instead post the actual code in the form of an "MCVE" as specified in the above link.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Component for filtering a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28621617/418556).

Comment: Sorry ,this i my first time i ask in stack overflow

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @Code-Apprentice (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) No need for apologies! You can [edit] your own question at any time.

Comment: Please show a **complete** code example which we can copy and paste and run ourselves. You should also describe in more detail what the program does and how you want to act differently. See [ask] for more suggestions to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `JList` you could use a single column `JTable`. A `JTable` supports the ability to filter the rows of data in the table.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example to get you started.

You can even make the JTable look more like a JList by following these suggestions: [How to create a JTable which appears as JList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574637/how-to-create-a-jtable-which-appears-as-jlist/52582391#52582391)