# How do I add ScrollPane when many rows are added?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, resultset

I am trying to create a Frame where Student's name and Roll no. will be shown. All the student with the same name will be shown there along with their roll no. For example if someone search for harry i want all the students whose name is harry to appear in the frame. I have a ResultSet of statement `select * from student where name = 'harry'`.

But I am not able to understand how would I add scrollbars to the JFrame if there are too many rows(which would be the case when there are too many harry in the database).

I am beginner in Java Swing, so please help me out in this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIU a scroll pane for a table will only show scroll bars if there is more rows of data than the table can display in a single view. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data, or use existing data, like font lists or Unicode character names, to replace the DB. BTW *"I am beginner in Java Swing, so please help me out.."* Is that meant to mean that when you are no longer a beginner, we should ignore you? Questions on SO are answered partly by our ability (& time), but get most attention when ..

Comment: .. they are well researched and well expressed. This question shows little sign of either.

Comment: BTW *"AFAIU a scroll pane for a table will only show scroll bars if there is more rows of data than the table can display in a single view."* That should have been started with *"AFAIR.."* because, yes, [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28621618/418556) shows the effect. Hey, gimme a break, I wrote it half a decade ago!

Comment: When you create the JTable (I'm guessing), you add it to a JScrollPane.  The scroll bars will show if they are needed (the default operation), unless you specify otherwise.  Here's Oracle's tutorial, How to Use Tables.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html