# Using char from the text from Jtextfield box and if it is matched with half the preferred string, show the preferred string in the display box

Tags: java, string, swing, char, character

It is my first time posting a question here. I am currently stuck with my music searching app project. In which when you search a music, the app will show the music name you want to search in the display box, and then you click play, the music will be played. But for now, I can't think of a way. As far as I can think of is want to get the text from the Jtextfield search box I created that the user enter to search, and use all the character in there, if it is matched with the string I preferred up to half of the string, then complete it all and show in display box. (For example, "payphone" entered in the search box, and the string I can preferred is "Payphone - Maroon 5," then the display box will show "Payphone - Maroon 5."

Here is my code, you guys can check it for more understanding about what I'm saying.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class playbackMp3 implements ActionListener {

    Font appFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);
    Font buttonFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField searchBar, songDisplay;
    JButton[] functionButtons = new JButton[5];
    JButton play, pause, prev, next, search;
    String searchBox;
    String payphone_maroon5 = "Payphone - Maroon 5";
    
    boolean searchSong = false;
    public playbackMp3() {
        
        //gui
        frame = new JFrame("MP3");
        frame.setSize(320, 140);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        
        searchBar = new JTextField();
        searchBar.setBounds(23,8, 164, 25);
        searchBar.setFont(appFont);
        searchBar.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
        
        songDisplay = new JTextField();
        songDisplay.setBounds(23, 38, 253, 25);
        songDisplay.setFont(appFont);
        songDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        songDisplay.setEditable(false);
        songDisplay.setBorder(null);
        songDisplay.setText("Searching song to listen...");
        //songDisplay.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        play = new JButton("PLAY");
        pause = new JButton("PAUSE");
        prev = new JButton("PREV");
        next = new JButton("NEXT");
        search = new JButton ("SEARCH");
        
        functionButtons [0] = play;
        functionButtons [1] = pause;
        functionButtons [2] = next;
        functionButtons [3] = prev;
        functionButtons [4] = search;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            
            functionButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            functionButtons[i].setFont(buttonFont);
            functionButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
            functionButtons[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            
        }
        
        search.setBounds(192, 8, 84, 24);
        play.setBounds(10, 68, 64, 25);
        pause.setBounds(79, 68, 74, 25);
        next.setBounds(158, 68, 66, 25);
        prev.setBounds(229, 68, 66, 25);
        
        frame.add(prev);
        frame.add(next);
        frame.add(pause);
        frame.add(play);
        frame.add(songDisplay);
        frame.add(search);
        frame.add(searchBar);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playbackMp3 mp3 = new playbackMp3();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == search) {
            searchBox = searchBar.getText();
            songDisplay.setText(searchBox);
//          if(searchBox == check_custhekid) {
//              songDisplay.setText("YES");
//          }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use a `DocumentListener` to listen for changes in the text field and then do your processing every time text is added or removed. Maybe use a `JTable` to display your songs. Then you can filter the table as you type the name of the song you search for. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.

Comment: Here is an [example of filtering a `JTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28621618/418556).. But check out the link from @camickr before proceeding.